# How can I fill my django form in two different template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
Person_ID = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
p_SSN = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=10)
p_fName = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=15)
p_lName = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=25)
p_phoneNum = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=11)
p_birthDate = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
p_Email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
p_Password = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)
```

At step 1 I want to fill my form **except** p_Email and p_Password.

In step 2 (means **next template**) I want to initial p_Email and p_Password.

this is my django form:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
p_fName = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
p_lName = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
p_SSN = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
p_phoneNum = forms.CharField(max_length=11)
p_birthDate = forms.DateField()
p_Email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
p_Password = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ['p_fName', 'p_lName', 'p_SSN', 'p_phoneNum', 'p_birthDate', 'p_Email', 'p_Password']
```

This is my views.py:

```
def new_student(request):
newStudentForm = PersonForm(request.POST or None)
if newStudentForm.is_valid():
    newStudentForm.save()
return render(request,
              'signUp_student.html',
              {'form': newStudentForm})
```

And my template for step 1 is :

```
<form action="{%  url 'new_student' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
    {{ form.p_fName }}<br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br>
    {{ form.p_lName }}<br>
    <label for="firstName">SSN Code</label><br>
    {{ form.p_SSN }}<br>
    <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label><br>
    {{ form.p_birthDate }}<br>
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label><br>
    {{ form.p_phoneNum }}<br><br>
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

How can I initial my fields of class in different template?

Thanks for giving your time to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your models in to two forms. After splitting your forms you can then write two views for two different forms to be processed and then send to two templates.

The forms.py file looks like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['p_fName', 'p_lName', 'p_SSN', 'p_phoneNum', 'p_birthDate']

class PersonFormTwo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Person
        fields=['p_Email','p_Password']
```

now the views.py file:

```
def new_student(request):
    newStudentForm = forms.PersonForm(request.POST or None)
    newStudentFormTwo=forms.PersonFormTwo(request.POST)
    if newStudentForm.is_valid():
        newStudentForm.save()
    return render(request,
                  'signup_student.html',
                  {'form': newStudentForm})

def new_student_two(request):
    newStudentFormTwo=forms.PersonFormTwo(request.POST)
    if newStudentFormTwo.is_valid():
        newStudentFormTwo.save()
    return render(request,
                  'next.html',
                  {'form': newStudentFormTwo})
```

urls.py file:

```
path('next/',views.new_student_two,name='next'),
```

next.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" name="" value="save">
  </body>
</html>
```

That's all. The other option is to create two different models, connect one model with other using the foreignkey field and the rest is same.

Comment: Does it handle null values for email and password?
I mean, is it not going to insert two records in our database?

Comment: you have to told that in your model whether to save null value or not!

Comment: I think your solution, makes out this situation that insert one record that p_email and p_password has null value and in second template we have another records that p_email and p_password (just these two) isn't null.

Comment: try and run your code and see the result. if it happens like you mention i have given you the second option that is creating two different models, connect one model with other using the foreignkey field and the rest is same.